# Rhythmbox interface

Tags: rhythmbox

All versions of Rhythmbox I've used looked something like this

[image]

Notice at the top, there are two wide toolbars, one with buttons, the other with the song title and progress slider.

Apparently, it's possible to unify the two to make Rhythmbox look something like this:

[image]

Anyone knows how?

PS: I use Ubuntu 10.04 and Rhythmbox 0.12.8 bundled with it.

Comment: ... where did you get that second screenshot?

Comment: huh? that link is the first screenshot.  Where did you read that you can unify the title with the toolbar?

Comment: I've not read it anywhere. The two are unified in the second screenshot, and I was hoping to accomplish as much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rhythmbox version that was first [hosted on sourceforge](http://rhythmbox.sourceforge.net/) (v0.8.5) first existed with a GUI as per your second screenshot.

Since the software was moved under the Gnome umbrella, the GUI has been changed as per your first screenshot.  Unfortunately, you cannot reskin rhythmbox to have the old GUI.

There is a rhythmbox fork:

[image]

The second screenshot looks very much like the proposed "Rhythm-e" elementary version of Rhythmbox - this is/was a fork of Rhythmbox proposed for Elementary OS.

The current status of Rhythm-e looks rather quiet looking at [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/rhythm-e)

The screenshot is from a [webupd8 article](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/09/rhythm-e-elementary-rhythmbox-is-on-its.html)

There are some nice screenshots of this on [deviantart](http://ammonkey.deviantart.com/art/Rhythm-e-201062014) - Rhythm-e is deprecated and is no longer being developed, [Beatbox](https://launchpad.net/~sgringwe/+archive/beatbox) which is the new Music Player from the elementary team was favored over Rhythm-e.  However this is not available in Lucid.

Comment: Rhythm-e is Deprecated and is no longer being developed, Beatbox which is the new Music Player from the elementary team was favored over Rhythm-e.

Comment: Looks great. I wish something like that was available for Lucid.

Comment: @mikewhatever - agreed - skins for rhythmbox is a long sought after feature.  Not yet implemented as yet :(

Comment: @mikewhatever You *can* as the articles notes, get the code & compile Rhythm-e in Lucid, it's in a bzr branch.

Comment: Might give it a shot, though I was hoping to avoid compiling. It seems that whatever they were trying to do was abandoned. Not sure it even worked.

Comment: @mikewhatever - see my edit... hope this helps.